# Cartthrob - Presales questions

Tags: cartthrob, json, api

I have just sent this to the CT team but am open to as much advice as possible so thought id put it out here too. Is this type of Q even allowed on here?

**Q:** 
I am just reading the docs trying to decide which route to go down for a online food delivery system.

It needs to integrate with a POS (Revel Systems). In the [docs](https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/pages/cartthrob_order_manager/index.html#erp-integration) it says to contact CT as may be able to offer with information on integrating with POS's

> "If you would like to integrate CartThrob with a Warehouse system,
>   Point of Sale system, ERP, or other post-order process, please contact
>   us for a consultation and we can give you an overview of what is
>   possible. Though every ERP system requires a unique integration, we
>   have a set of scaffolding for creating ERP integrations that offers a
>   push-pull API for sending and receiving data in a secure manner using
>   ExpressionEngine's built in user authentication. Our scaffolding
>   system offers you local integration using command line applications or
>   via publicly accessible web services."

The API that Revel Systems (POS) uses is Django Tasty Pie (REST) (https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

SO, I will need to using a webservice to sync inventory, order history and mainly to push orders to their system.

Without going into too much detail could you answer the below Q's?

- Do you know if the synchronisation will be possible with CT/webservice?
- They are accepting Cash on Delivery ONLY (Its a food delivery service), would I be able to push new website orders to their POS?
- What would be the best method to keep the inventory up-to-date on a regular basis whilst being linked to their POS?
- What format would CT need to receive the data to keep it synced? CSV/Webservice?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds pretty good that their POS (is it just a POS? Not an ERP too?) has a rest API. That means that in the grand scheme of things it should be a nice job to push and pull data.

There are a few ways to do things, but essentially, Cartthrob has hooks for most major events through the order process. You can simply fire off data to their API to inform them of orders/inventory etc and they can do something similar by posting info on inventory updates to EE which can be consumed easily enough.

There will be questions about inventory updates that could clash (someone has item in cart, you update inventory from the POS, item no longer exists online etc) but all in all, a very doable project with CT.

Best format would be json one assumes if you will be using web services to throw data around. I guess you could use a CSV, but, not sure you would want to.

John

Comment: I'm with Vector-- we're the people behind CartThrob. I agree with this answer and think you'll have no problem doing what you want using CartThrob's hooks/API.